# Can I kill and revive the same creature with Betrayal of Flesh entwined?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Betrayal of Flesh](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Betrayal%20of%20Flesh) reads

> Choose one — Destroy target creature; or return target creature card from your graveyard to the battlefield.

> Entwine—Sacrifice three lands. (Choose both if you pay the entwine cost.)

If I cast it with entwine, can I target the same creature with the first half (while it is on the battlefield) and the second half (when it is in the graveyard)? Or do I pick the target for the second half before the first half resolves?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. All targets are picked as part of casting the spell. The spell resolves and places the creature in the graveyard far later.